# LIRC null values, Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspbian, gpio, kernel, remote, lirc

I tried to install an IR receiver on my Pi 3B under Raspbien Buster, kernel 4.19.
I managed to install lirc, and when I use `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` I read pulses.

The problem is the following : when I try to record a remote with irrecord, I can see that every codes stored in the conf files are 0x00, null values. I used two different remotes, and the result is the same, for any button.

I know that using lirc became harder since Buster and gpio_ir, so is there a solution to make it work in my case, or does another driver exists now ?
My final use would be in a Python script